# Замена клавиатуры тг-бота с reply на inline в aiogram на python

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, inline

Я отправляю боту смс, в этот момент мне надо удалить оставшуюся после прошлого действия клавиатуру типа "reply keyboard markup" и прикрепить к отправленному только что смс inline-клавиатуру.
Много решений видел, но не одно не помогло. Ниже приведу код последнего оставленного метода, но и он выдает ошибку (Telegram server says Bad Request: message can't be edited). Пожалуйста, не присылайте решения через удаление смс и повторную его отправку. Оно мне просто не нравится, как в боте происходит промигивание смс.
В результате должно быть смс с inline-keyboard и без оставшихся reply кнопок.

```
#Все библиотеки и их составляющие, которые нужны в коде, заимпортированы
b_Account: KeyboardButton = KeyboardButton(text='Аккаунт ')
b_Shop: KeyboardButton = KeyboardButton(text='Магазин ')
b_Referals: KeyboardButton = KeyboardButton(text='Рефералы ')
b_Collection: KeyboardButton = KeyboardButton(text='Коллекция ')
m_Start: ReplyKeyboardMarkup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[[b_Collection,b_Shop],[b_Account,b_Referals]], resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
b_Back: InlineKeyboardButton = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад ', callback_data='back')
b_Rename: InlineKeyboardButton = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Поменять имя аккаунта ✏', callback_data='rename acc')
m_MyInfo: InlineKeyboardMarkup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[b_Back,b_Rename]])

#...
# !ВАЖНО! Ранее было отправлено такое смс от бота await message.answer(f"Выберите пункт из кнопочного меню",reply_markup=m_Start)
#...

@dp.message(F.text)
async def start_menu(message: Message):
    txt=message.text
    if txt=="Аккаунт ":
        mess=await message.answer(f"ID аккаунта: {message.from_user.id}",reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.from_user.id, message_id=mess.message_id, text=f"ID аккаунта: {message.from_user.id}", reply_markup=m_MyInfo)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я не понял, что именно надо уточнить, по-моему я всё сказал.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь редактировать из бота сообщение **пользователя**, к сообщению пользователя нельзя прикрепить клавиатуру. Прибавьте к id пользователя единицу в последней строке, тогда он будет редактировать сообщение с ответом id

Comment: Так ведь в переменную mess я записываю ответ от бота, а значит mess.message_id выдает id смс от бота. Я попробовал, прибавление единицы создало новую ошибку - не найдено смс для редакции

Comment: Да, и правда, не заметил. Как я понимаю, нужно в параметры передавать не message_id, а inline_message_id при редактировании. Возможно, это поможет

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало. Пишет - парметра  inline_message_id не существует